# Force Bootstrap Nav-Brand to overflow

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been having issues with the Bootstrap nav-bar with ASP.NET mvc. In my layout file, I have a line like this: `<div class="navbar-brand">This is a very long string I want to go in the title.</div>`. My issue is that, when the screen gets too narrow to have the text fit on one line, I would like it to use ellipsis instead of wrapping to the next line. I tried some css, like so:

```
.navbar-brand    {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-wrap:none;
}
```

to no effect. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out, you've to define a width to make the whole thing work and set `overflow: hidden` + `white-space: nowrap`. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guntLygm/)**

```
.navbar-brand{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That is almost perfect, for some reason when I use your solution the text wraps even where there is plenty of room left on the screen, but I think that's probably something wrong on my side. Thank you :)